# to start shell from a certain directory in linux

Tags: linux, shell, directory, location

in XP I could write a bat file with `start` in it and put it wherever I want to click and run cmd with the location I put the file in, how to do that in linux? Thanks

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com ?

Comment: You want Linux to behave like XP?

Comment: I want a file that does this:  if I put it in a directory f, and if I double click it, the shell is gonna pop up with the default directory to be f

Answer (score 0):

This command gives you the directory path of the script, as called:

```
dirname -- "$0"
```

To use it (safely) in a script, you can for example do this:

```
script_dir="$(dirname -- "$0")x"
script_dir="${script_dir%x}"
cd -- "${script_dir}/foo"
# Now you're in the directory "foo" below where the script was saved
```

Answer (score 0):

cd into the directory you wish to operate from near the start of your code.

You can't be certain where your code will be called from and thus you can't be certain what the working directory will be in your code. Only way around this is to cd to wherever you need to be within your script.

Actually re-reading your question, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to ask...

Are you looking for a way to call another script from within a script?

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble, starting the script from the Desktop/Panel/Menu: How do you start your application?

- Menu
- Icon in Panel
- Icon in Desktop
- something else (which?)

I'm using xUbuntu, and with german translation, so you have to be flexible in adopting this solution for the panel:

- right click on panel
- add new element
- choose 'new starter'
- for xubuntu, name, description program: xfterm4 - yours might be 'gterm' or 'xterm' or 'gnome-terminal'
- choose a different terminal icon than that for $HOME
- choose 'working directory': '/your/path/here'
- done

I guess for a starter icon on the desktop, the way is similar. For Menu-entries consult your administrator. :) Maybe similar too.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why not? Many users start scripts only via the GUI.